# Display recently changed items

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to show a list of recently updated documents on our Sharepoint online intranet site. I've tried 2 things, neither of which are working (it appears for the same reason).

1. Adding the webpart 'Recently Changed Items'
2. Adding the webpart 'Search Results' and selecting 'Recently Changed Items (System)'.

In both cases, the Search Results Preview displays the relevant items, however, when I click OK nothing is shown on the web parts.

[image]

[image]

Any Ideas?

**UPDATE**

I have been developing using Chrome browser. In IE the search results do show up. Anyone know a fix for chrome?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Search Results` WebPart Then Configure it as below

- Select a query `Local SharePoint Results (System)`
- Keyword filter `Only return items`
- Query Text `Path:"https://yourSP.sharepoint.com" +` your Keyword in this case will be         `(contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True)`

Comment: Do you know why the options above aren't working? Your answer is ok but it would be good to show recently updated web pages, documents, etc from the whole site collection rather than from just one list.

Comment: I updated my answer... test it and let my know if you still get any issue

Comment: Still no luck. I've updated my question as the results show in IE but not chrome.